# Add WebView to Progressive Web App (PWA)?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I have been creating Progressive Web App (PWA) using Angular 6.

Tt's possible to add WebView to my application?

How I can do to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If you wanted to do the other way around, load your PWA inside a WebView, that would be possible.

To do it all yourself, there are tutorials you can follow:

- Android: https://medium.com/@stevesohcot/andriod-studio-webview-tutorial-4651701d7d1a
- iOS: https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/webview-ios-tutorial-ios11

But it may be easier to use a wrapper, to set up a suitable environment for the PWA:

- Android: https://github.com/xtools-at/Android-PWA-Wrapper
- iOS: https://github.com/xtools-at/iOS-PWA-Wrapper

---

You can also get some good tips from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49645844/hybrid-app-depending-on-server-side-patch/49656258).

Amongst other things, it suggests using [PWA Builder](https://www.pwabuilder.com/), which does look quite nice.  From the site:

> PWA Builder was founded by Microsoft as a community guided, open source project to help move PWA adoption forward.

I think it will create your Android and iOS builds all in one go.

---

[This paper discusses](https://ai.google/research/pubs/pub46739) the current state of play (2018) and also has some example code for **checking which PWA features are available** in the WebView you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Progressive web app itself is a web app and so you can't add webview to it, which is only applicable when you are having a native app and want to show some web content.

Why would you want to have a webview in a webapp (PWA is also a web app, its just that it can be installed to home screen).

Comment: Don't know about OP but I have an answer to "why would you want a WebView in a webapp": I have an Android-only native app which acts as a Web browser but adds language-learning aids to any Chinese text it finds as you browse, it does this by injecting JS into WebView and providing callbacks. I'd like to get this onto iOS, but native iOS development has too many cost barriers, so I'd like to do it as a web app, but I can't, because web apps don't provide a WebView that can fetch any site and provide callbacks to let me add the language-learning aids to the text. I just have to say "get Android"

Comment: @Silas your usecase is webview in a native app, which make sense. Webviews are just for that purpose. It runs webpages I side a native app, which is not web. But PWA itself is a webapp running inside a browser. If you have a usecase to have both native and web code, in Android, now there is Trusted Web Activity, which just does that.